# error with sending email

Tags: apex

I am using the below method to send email, but it is giving me an error saying -

> common.apex.methods.MessagingStaticMethods$EmailExecutionException:
>   SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, List has no rows for assignment to SObject:

Note - the parameters caseid, tgtObjId and toAddress, etId all are having values in debug.

Debug log :

> -mail----
>
> Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=null;;getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=null;getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=null;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=null;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=003e000000jotwPAAQ;getTemplateId=00Xe0000000EnBxEAK;getToAddresses=(THIS
>   CONTAINS LIST OF VALID EMAIL
>    IDS);getWhatId=500e000000AO87rAAD;isTreatBodiesAsTemplate=false;isTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient=true;isUserMail=false;]

```
private List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> sendEmail(Id caseId, Id tgtObjId, Id etId, String[] toAddress){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    system.debug('-----inside sendemail----->+ '---tgtObjId--'+tgtObjId+'----et.Id---'+et.Id+'-----caseId---'+caseId+'----toAddress--'+toAddress);       
    String [] ccaddress = new string []{'Xxxx@gmail.com'}; 

    mail.setSenderDisplayName('abcd');
    mail.setTargetObjectId(tgtObjId); 
    mail.setWhatId(caseId);
    mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
    mail.setccAddresses(ccaddress);

    system.debug('500-------------mail---->' +mail);
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> res = new List<Messaging.SendEmailResult>();  
    try{
        res = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   
    }
    catch(Exception exp){
          system.debug('500.1-------------error email -->' +exp);
    }
    system.debug('500.2-------------mail---->' +mail+'--------------res----->'+res);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any email triggers?

Comment: No..calling this method from the same class.

Comment: Is that visualforce email?

Comment: yes..using vf template at et.id...

Comment: It may be the case that problem is in that email template referenced components controller